# Handling Memory Bloats in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, d3.js

I am writing an application using JavaScript and D3. The application takes in data from the user and makes a pack map.

Whenever the user feeds too much data to be visualized the browser will freeze. This is unavoidable as the user is feeding too much data and the pack layout is can not handle all that data.

I would like to know if there is a way I can detect when the browsers memory is about to fill so I can crash gracefully? Is there a way to probe the available memory dynamically or even statically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In chrome you can use `window.performance.memory` or try this library https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js/ or https://github.com/paulirish/memory-stats.js

Comment: Thanks for the lead. Looked into all three ways of doing things. Maybe I am doing something wrong but my application seems to not be making any difference to the JSHeap. No matter what I do the amount of memory used seems to be the same using those methods. When I use the chrome inspect element and look at the performance I clearly see a significant rise in the JSHeap, up to 50MB used before crashing.